# Calculate x/y position on an image from latitude/longitude

Tags: model-view-controller, gps, kml, latitude-longitude, transformation

I already did some research but none answer did fit to my problem:
I have an image (jpeg) that is represented by a latlonbox:

https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference?hl=de#latlonbox
So I have North, South, East and West information that form the image, right? Is the N/W the top left point and the S/E the bottom-rightt point?

The image has a size of 4000x2000. In my mvc application i reduced size to 1500x750 pixel.

Now I am trying to achieve to calculate the x/y position on this image by getting a latitude/longitude input. How can I achieve this?

I found this link:
http://code.google.com/p/geographical-dot-net/source/browse/trunk/GeographicalDotNet/GeographicalDotNet/Projection/GoogleMapsAPIProjection.cs

But I don't have any zoom information and I also don't understand how to start, because I have a jpeg and the kml information with latlonbox.

Thanks for any help

Comment: This is an advanced topic, which is easily solved only when the picture has a small map scale (some kilometers from E-W or N-S). For greater scales, you need to know which projection paramters have been used by the picture creator. (Often it is a mercartor projection). Or if the projection is unknwon you need a couple of reference points in the picture with knwon coordinates and use the (complex) helmert transformation.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your reply! Yes, in my case the kilometers are very small, maybe only some hundred meters. I tried to solve it with two linear equations, would that be appropriate? 
Using the first link, with the example of latlonbox I did the following:

```
WN: (-90,8714285289695/48,25475939255556)  <=> X: (0/0)
ES: (-90,86591508839973/48,25207367852141) <=> Y: (1500/750)

E: -90,86591508839973
S: 48,25207367852141
W: -90,8714285289695
N: 48,25475939255556

Diff EW:  0,00551344056977
Diff_SN:  0,00268571403415
```

I define two functions:
    f_X1: m*x_lon + b where f_X1 is the X coordinate and x_lon the longitude value
    f_X2: m*x_lat + b where f_X2 is the Y coordinate and x_lat the latitude value
Function to get X-coordinate:

```
m = (1500/Diff_EW) = 272062 (rounded)
```

Insert a known X/Longitude-Pair in function f_X1:
    1500 = E * 272062 + b
    b = 1500 - (E * 272062)
    b = 24722662 ( rounded)

```
=> f_X1: 272062x + 24722662
```

Same procedure to get f_X2:

```
m  = (750/-Diff_SN) = - 279255(rounded)
```

Insert a known Y/Latitude-Pair in functon f_X2:

```
750 = S * (-279255) + b
b = 750 - (S*(-279255))
b = 13475382

f_X2: -279255x + 13475382
```

If I insert the values for East and West (E and W) I will get the X-coordinates (approximately 1500 and 0; deviates due to rounding)

If I insert the values for South and North (S and N) I will get the Y-coordinates (approximately 750 and 0; deviates due to rounding)

Is this a correct way to do it in this case? I assumed the function to be linear, I don't know if that's correct.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: While this is a couple of years old, you should of edited your question rather than write an extension to is as an answer.